# how do you create the build section for an RPM spec for a golang project?

Tags: go, fedora, rpm

Following the steps here:

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/02/rpm-build-package-example/

I'm making a RPM package with my program I wrote in golang.

Do I need to actually make the RPM compile the go code? Or is there a way include just binary inside the package? (This is what I did for the .deb version.)

I'm confused because this would mean golang would have to be installed on the end users machine?

Comment: It should be the same as deb, just the binary.

Comment: i see! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429511/how-to-use-rpmbuild-to-build-a-rpm-package-from-binary-tarball thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared to general RPM packaging examples, the Golang has some specific bits. You can read about them here: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Golang/

At the end of that page are some examples.